# перенос данных между сценами

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

В определённый момент нужно перенести счет игрока из одной сцены в другую, а в текущей сцене обнулить счёт. **static** и прочее сохраняют счет, чего не нужно.

Подробнее.
В сцене игрок набирает очки по времени.  Когда время вышло, происходит рестарт игры.  То есть все сначала. (С НУЛЯ!).
Набранные же очки нужно перенести в другую сцену, где ведется статистика.

Comment: ничё не понятно. кто куда перешел? вы куда то перешли но остались там же или что? можно как-то яснее объяснить что вы хотите? и почему вы не можете обнулить статическую переменную находясь на сцене где нужно обнулять счет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявите класс какой-нить, в котором будут мета данные игры. Сделайте его `static`.

```
public class GameMetaData{
     private Dictionary<string, int> m_Points; // набранные очки в зависимости от сцены

     private static GameMetaData m_Instance;
     public GameMetaData(){
         Points = new Dictionary<string, int>();
     }
     public int GetPoints(string sceneName){
          if(!m_Points.ContainsKey(sceneName)){ 
              m_Points.Add(sceneName, 0);
          }

          return m_Points[sceneName];
     }
     public int SetPoints(string sceneName, int value){
          if(m_Points.ContainsKey(sceneName)){
             m_Points[sceneName] = value;
          else
             m_Points.Add(sceneName, value);
     }

     public GameMetaData GetInstance(){
         if(m_Instance == null)
            m_Instance= new GameMetaData ();

         return m_Instance;
     }
}
```

Теперь в первой сцене перед переходом на другую сцены вызывайте:

```
GameMetaData.GetInstance().SetPoints("second_scene", 999); // устанавливаем для второй сцены очки из текущей сены
GameMetaData.GetInstance().SetPoints("first_scene", 0);  // в ьекущей сцене обнуляем
```

Теперь в другой сцене в `Start` или `Awake` получаем:

```
public class SecondSceneScript : MonoBehaviour{
    private in m_Points;

    public void Start(){
        m_Points =  GameMetaData.GetInstance().GetPoints("second_scene");
        // теперь в m_Points будет 999
    }

}
```

Можно без своих классов, сохраняя и получая, скажем, в/из [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).